# Is exposing good deeds

Tags: waswasa

Is watching the islamic videos in public is exposing our good deeds, i think that it is exposing of our goods deeds, and I can't open my mobile in public, like i have thought that what if any islamic notification came to me, and someone could see it (from 4 sides) and thinks that i am religious person, also when i in my room there is small holes in room, i get thought that if anybody see me from that hole to my mobile when iam watching islamic videos and he thinks I'm a religious person ,and I'm exposing my good deeds, is this valid question or waswas of shaitan